# Can we use the preposition "for" in this manner?

Tags: prepositions

Is it possible to use the preposition "for" with the perfect infinitive? Like so:

- It must really be hot in here for her to have taken so many clothes off.
- It must really be a serious matter for him to have been talking about it for so long, as he isn't one to make conversation.

Comment: Yes (those sentences are grammatical).

Comment: This is the _for_ infinitive subject marker that goes with the _to_ infinitive verb marker  (which is why it's technically called "the _for..to_ complementizer"). The subject of an infinitive is objective (_me, her, him, us, them_) and in this case retains the _for_ to mark it. Note that this whole infinitive clause is a purpose clause, and therefore may be fronted if desired: _For her to have taken so many clothes off, it must really be hot in here_.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely correct.

Clarification, though: the preposition is not actually introducing an infinitive but just an object of the preposition ("her" and "him" in your examples).  You can see this by how "for her" and "for him" can be taken out of the sentences.

Comment: Actually _for_ is introducing the subject noun phrase of the infinitive clause, just as _to_ introduces the verb phrase of that clause. Since the subjects of most infinitives aren't present -- either they're understood, like _I want to leave_ or indefinite like _It's hard to do_ -- the _for_ part usually doesn't appear. But if an infinitive with a subject appears at the beginning of a sentence, the _for_ is required: _For her to leave now would be a mistake_ is correct, but **Her to leave now would be a mistake* is terrible.

Comment: Many reconstructions are available that don't directly connect the infinitive to a particular subject.  "To leave now would be a mistake for her."  "For her, it would be a mistake to leave now."  And "For her, to leave now would be a mistake."  All of which could have different shades of meaning.

Comment: Yes, adverb movements often attempt to convey different shades of meaning. Notice, however, that _her_ is in fact the subject of each of the infinitives you mention. With the predicate _be a mistake_, there is the possibility of an experiencer _for_-phrase, which need not be the subject of a following complement: _For her, it would be a mistake if he left_. But generally not with infinitives: **For her, it would be a mistake for him to leave.*